# Convert value stored in a varchar to date time in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have a date stored in varchar variable
I want to covert it to datetime format so that I could update the date to a column with type datetime

```sql
declare @dt_original as varchar(30)

set @dt_original original='1997-12-22 00:00:00.000'
```

I have tried

```sql
cast(@dt_original as date time)
Convert(datetime,@dt_original)
```

But nothing worked

Always throwing "conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

Comment: It works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d4597d685032ae549e81d039e1d29496

Comment: If you want the variable to hold a date, why declare it as a `varchar` in the first place?

Comment: It won't for non-Americans @forpas . For example, if your British: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=11b5ac4f883945f9845c83eca04cf6b0). Despite what Microsoft *thought* (they've corrected it now for the new date and time data types) the rest of the world didn't read dates in the format `yyyy-dd-MM`.

Comment: My application stores date as varchar

Answer (score 0):

The idea of using `convert` was correct, but you're missing the style pattern matching your string. In this case, it's 121:

```sql
CONVERT(DATETIME, @dt_original, 121)
```